# Material ui dateRangePicker not closing on date select @material-ui

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am using mui dateRangePicker and it is not closing on selecting date range @material-ui

It should auto close after selecting date range.

I have seen it is closing dateRangePicker and then again focus is coming back to the control due that is is not closing after full range selection

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.